# Unit Test fails after upgrading to angular8

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I upgraded the project from Angular7 to Angular8. (for now, I haven't upgraded Nx, the current version used is "@nrwl/nx": "7.8.7",)

After upgrade, my application runs successfully (without any issues in build or deploy).

When I run the test cases by putting `"codeCoverage": true` in angular.json file it fails and throws below error.

script used

```
"test:appone": "ng test --project=app-one --no-watch",
```

Log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test:one' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest:one', 'test:one', 'posttest:one' ]
5 info lifecycle proj-micro-apps@1.1.0~pretest:one: proj-micro-apps@1.1.0
6 info lifecycle proj-micro-apps@1.1.0~test:one: proj-micro-apps@1.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle proj-micro-apps@1.1.0~test:one: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle proj-micro-apps@1.1.0~test:one: PATH: C:\Users\KBharambe\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\NX8New\proj-micro-apps\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\1E\NomadBranch\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\KBharambe\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\KBharambe\scoop\apps\maven\current\bin;C:\Users\KBharambe\scoop\shims;C:\Users\KBharambe\.windows-build-tools\python27\;C:\Users\KBharambe\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3;C:\Users\KBharambe\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\KBharambe\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\KBharambe\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\KBharambe\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\KBharambe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\KBharambe\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\KBharambe\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\KBharambe\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs
9 verbose lifecycle proj-micro-apps@1.1.0~test:one: CWD: D:\NX8New\proj-micro-apps
10 silly lifecycle proj-micro-apps@1.1.0~test:one: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'ng test --project=app-one  --no-watch' ]
11 silly lifecycle proj-micro-apps@1.1.0~test:one: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle proj-micro-apps@1.1.0~test:one: Failed to exec test:one script
13 verbose stack Error: proj-micro-apps@1.1.0 test:one: `ng test --project=app-one  --no-watch`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\KBharambe\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\KBharambe\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid proj-micro-apps@1.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\NX8New\proj-micro-apps
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test:one"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error proj-micro-apps@1.1.0 test:one: `ng test --project=app-one  --no-watch`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the proj-micro-apps@1.1.0 test:one script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

If I remove `"codeCoverage"` flag the test cases executes without any errors but I won't get any coverage.

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
================================================================================
```

I'm using karma jasmine for the same

```
    "karma": "4.4.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "0.6.0",
    "jasmine-reporters": "2.3.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "2.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "2.0.1",
```

ng --version

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.20
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.803.21
@angular-devkit/core               8.3.20
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.20
@angular/cdk                       8.2.3
@angular/cli                       8.3.20
@angular/flex-layout               8.0.0-beta.27
@angular/material                  8.2.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter   8.2.3
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   8.3.21
@schematics/angular                8.3.20
@schematics/update                 0.803.20
ng-packagr                         5.0.0
rxjs                               6.5.3
typescript                         3.4.5
webpack                            4.39.2
```

I tried it with multiple node versions but still same.

Can you please let me know what can be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider migrating jest at least to upgrade unit test cases related dependencies

```sh
nx migrate @nrwl/jest@<new-version> --from=@nrwl/jest@<old-version>
```

You might have to run based on output of above command

```sh
npm install
nx migrate --run-migrations=migrations.json
```

Comment: considering that the OP question is for Jasmine then this answer is not exactly related. You're answering with Jest and Nx upgrade which the OP doesn't have at all, so this answer probably won't help much